# Toolbar is transparent pre-lollipop

Tags: android

So I've looked around and can't find an answer to this. I have a toolbar which shows up fine for anything lollipop and up but looks like the following for pre-lollipop devices:

[image: wonky toolbar]

Here is my code for the styles and everything:

style xml file

```
<style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/appStyleSpinner</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primaryColor</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryColorDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accentColor</item>
    <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="actionModeStyle">@style/myActionMode</item>
</style>

<style name="myActionMode" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionMode">
    <item name="background">@color/primaryColor</item>
</style>
```

toolbar xml file

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/appbar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
android:elevation="4dp"
android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">
...
```

Comment: Try remove <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
from your styles

Comment: I need that when I'm deleting items from a list though because the little delete icon appears in the toolbar on a long press

Comment: In your xml file you don't use the theme you declared. If this doesn't solve the problem, what is wrong with the rendering?

Comment: yeah that didn't fix anything when I changed it. And I don't understand your question?

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the problem! In my xml file for the main screen, I had

```
<include layout="@layout/app_bar"
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"/>    

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/parmesan_bg"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:contentDescription="photo of delicious dinner"/>
```

which was causing the toolbar to load behind the image instead of in front of it. So move the "include layout" to after the imageview and voila, problem solved!